# How can I back up files from LG's Browser?

Tags: backup

In anticipation of my phone dying soon, I've been backing up every file on it. I'm using an LG G Flex, and it comes with a generic browser. Browser came with a "save for offline reading" function, which I used to use regularly, until I found out that nowhere in the file manager can I view or access these saved webpages, which makes backup much harder.

Since then, I've been using a separate app to save new webpages, and to back up the old ones I've been individually saving every page to Capture Plus (the browser's full page screen capture function).

I'm now down to my last webpage, but Capture Plus tells me that there isn't enough memory when I try to capture it as a screenshot.

This doesn't mean that there isn't enough memory in the location I'm saving to, because I know there is, so what gives?

The saved webpage that I'm trying to back up is one that has been removed from the internet, so I can't just go back to the same website and download it again.

I could take about 3,000 screenshots of the page and later assemble them into one (it's a pretty long page), but if there's a way around that approach, I'd like to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

LG's built-in backup is very good, alternatively you can use adb backup.

1. `adb backup -all` Now unlock your device and confirm the backup operation.
2. Unplug old phone plug in new phone, `adb restore backup.ab`
3. Now unlock your device and confirm the restore operation.